# Configuring Email-to-Fax Server with Gmail

Tags: windows-10, email, fax

I am trying to set up emailtofax

https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=emailtofax

on Windows 10.

First of all, does anyone know if it works on Windows 10?

Second of all, the config file asks for a few different items that sound the same to me

- Username and Password: the POP username and password of the email account of the fax server where users send their email to.
- FaxServerEmailAddress:  The email address where users send their email to to be faxed.
- ReceiverEmailAddress: the email address where incoming faxes will be sent to.

I want to send a email to MYNAME@gmail.com and have it turned into a fax. So how do I configure this?

For a little background, I will paste the Readme.txt

> Email-to-Fax Server is a windows application that does the following:
>
> - Sends email attachments as faxes.
> - Sends faxes received as email attachments to a specified address or addresses.
>
> It obtains emails from a POP email account and sends the emails'
> attachments as faxes to the fax number specified in the subject line.
> It uses a SMTP account to send faxes received in the windows machine
> as email attachments. The user can configure the server using a
> standard Spring xml configuration file. The program is developed in C#
> and uses the internal Windows's Fax services as its foundation.
>
> The program also serves as a sample Spring.net application.
>
> How to use
>
> You need to create an email account for Email-to-Fax Server. To send
> email attachments as faxes, you and your users will send emails to
> this email address with the destination fax number in the email's
> subject line (e.g. (555)222-5656). The program will remove any
> non-numeric characters from the subject line, so you can format your
> number as you wish.
>
> To use Email-to-Fax Server you must:
>
> 1. Install the windows faxing services included in Windows. Use Windows components Add/Remove to do that.
> 2. Configure the fax services in Windows. This is usually done by right clicking the "Fax" icon and then going to "Properties" in the
>    "Printers and Faxes" folder. As of the current version, the name of
>    the fax to be used must be "Fax".
> 3. Edit the applicationContext.xml file found in the "Configuration" folder.
>
> The configuration file tells the program the POP settings to use for
> receiving the emails that will be sent as faxes and also the SMTP
> settings to use for sending received faxes. A list of the
> configuration values is shown here:
>
> SmtpServer: this must be the address of your smtp server that will be
> used by the program to send emails.
>
> SmtpPort: The port number of the above smtp server.
>
> PopServer: this must be the address of your POP server that will be
> used by the program to receive emails.
>
> PopPort: The port number of the above POP server.
>
> Username and Password: the POP username and password of the email
> account of the fax server where users send their email to.
>
> FaxServerEmailAddress:  The email address where users send their email
> to to be faxed.
>
> ReceiverEmailAddress: the email address where incoming faxes will be
> sent to.
>
> DeleteMessagesOnServer: true or false. If true, it will delete the
> emails received in the fax server's email account once they are ready
> to be faxed.
>
> ReceivedFaxEmailSubject: The subject line of the emails sent
> containing any incoming fax.
>
> ReceivedFaxEmailContent: The text body of the above mentioned email.
>
> RunEverySeconds: Specifies the interval in seconds when the program
> will check for new emails.
>
> ReceivedFaxesFolderPath: the folder path (absolute) that stores the
> received faxes as you specified when configuring the Windows Fax
> Services.
>
> ValidDomainName: The domain from which your users can send faxes from.
> Any email sent from an email address with a different domain will be
> rejected and NOT sent.

Comment: The project dates from 2017, so has a very good chance of working. But you won't know until you try.